# extracting numeric values from java code, without affecting variables with numbers

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have source code that i am trying to process by removing all numerical values from it,
for example:

```
                int x =14;
                float y=-3.14;
                int var1able = 3;
```

will be :

```
                 int x=;
                 float y=;
                 int var1able = ;
```

is it possible to do this with a regular expression?

Comment: Is it assured that after the = only "a number" followed by "a semicolon" occurs?

Comment: Not sure what you plan to do here, but the compiler will complain about `int x = ;`

Comment: What is ur requirement ?

Comment: What about `int x; x=1;`?

Comment: Where does the input come from? What are you gonna do with the output?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the variables to null(must use or cast integer for int) if that satisfies your requirements, but they cannot just be empty or else your compiler will yield errors.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(?<==)\s*[0-9.-]+\s*(?=;)` with empty string?

Comment: this matches numbers preceded by a space, but is not matching negative or float number, also, numerical values could be in function calls,
e.g. :

int y = SumFunction(1,5);

will be :

int y = sumFunction(,);

Comment: matches negative or float for me, but it could also match `-` or `.` because I was lazy with the regex.

Comment: i tried this :
[^A-Za-z]+-?\d+\.?
but it is still matching variables like    
int test01;